# Workling processes multiplying uncontrolably

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, workling, monit

We have a rails app running on passenger and we background process some tasks using a combination of RabbitMQ and Workling. The workling's worker process is started using the `script/workling_client` command. There is always only one worker process started, and the `script/workling_client` has a `:multiple => false` options, thus allowing only one instance. But sometimes, under mysterious circumstances which I haven't been able to track down, more worklings spawn up. If I let the system run for some time, more and more worklings appear. I'm not sure if these rogue worklings cause any problems, but it is still unsettling not to know why is it happening. We are using Monit to monitor the workling process. So if it dies, it will spawn it up again. But this still does not explain how come there are suddenly more than one of them.

So my question is: does anyone know what can be cause of this and how to make it stop? Is it possible that workling sometimes dies by itself, without deleting it's pid file? Could there be something wrong with the Daemons gem `workling_client` is build upon?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?
I'm experiencing the same thing... and I'm totally baffled by it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer - I have the same problems running RabbitMQ + Workling.
I'm using God to monitor the single workling process as well (:multiple => false)...
I found that the multiple worklings were eating up huge amounts of memory & causing serious resource usage, so it's important that I find a solution for this.

You might find this message thread helpful: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/ed8edd0368066292/5b17d91cc85c3ada?show_docid=5b17d91cc85c3ada&pli=1